# Trying To toggle text.. what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I'm trying to change and toggle this two texts.. but it hide when start the page!

```
$('.hide_show').toggle(function(){
    $('.hide_show').text('Hide');
}, function(){
    $('.hide_show').text('Show');
});
```

Comment: can u show remaining code snippet as well?

Comment: The toggle() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9. Make sure you have the right version.

Comment: @VinitSarvade partially accurate since there are 2 signatures for toggle. `toggle(function,function)` is deprecated though. The other version still exists

Comment: @charlietfl Absolutely. Yes there is a version that still exists as answered by Majid Parvin. But this one is been not only deprecated, but removed completely.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't define your text changes inside of callback functions; this will cause janky transitions (esp. when combined with animations).  Additionally, there isn't really a second input for  a function in `toggle`, see reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ .  I went ahead and replaced the code with something that works, give it a go.

```js
$("button").click(function (){
  $content = $('.content').toggle();
  $(this).text($content.is(":visible") ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide</button>
<div class="content">I really like to eat food</div>
```